FOP internal image processing - inverting colors
I am generating a pdf via xsl/fo.
In that base xml I am using <fo:external-graphic src="path2file">
The image is in TIF-Format and is converted by the internal image process.
The result image has converted colors to the original one.
Is there any chance to manipulate the internal image processing to not invert the colors?
Minimal example:
Base fo-xml-File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" master-name="normalPage">
         <fo:region-body region-name="region-body" margin="20mm 15mm 17mm 15mm"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence id="pages"  master-reference="normalPage">
      <fo:flow flow-name="region-body">
         <fo:table table-layout="fixed">
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-body>
               <fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-cell>
                     <fo:block>
                        <fo:external-graphic src="file:////path2image"
                                             scaling="non-uniform"
                                             content-height="scale-to-fit"
                                             content-width="48mm"/>
                     </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
               </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
         </fo:table>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>

Executing via console:
fop Version: 2.1
Path2fopExecutable -fo path2foFile -pdf path2targetPDFfile 2> path2LogFile

There is no special call of a image processing, regarding scaling. So, there is a internal image processing included with that effect.
I wonder how this is to configure to ensure not converting color, for example.

Ok, thanks for explaining the issue...
I guess a preprocessing of images to a JPEG is then to be a solution.
